# Getting Same Facebook "Like" count for different URLS

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add multiple "Like" buttons on the same page but specifying different like URL's

I have 2 URLs that I want to "Like" on a separate page

http://www.spoilertv.com/search/label/Brothers%20And%20Sisters
http://www.spoilertv.com/search/label/Better%20With%20You

Here is my code.

```
Better With You <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spoilertv.com%2Fsearch%2Flabel%2FBetter%2520With%2520You&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=150&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
Brothers and Sisters <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spoilertv.com%2Fsearch%2Flabel%2FBrothers%2520And%2520Sisters&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=150&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The problem is that they both show the same "Like" count.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the problem is that the spaces (%20) are converted to (%2520) within the Facebook iframe.

Try to use the space unicode (%20) directly:

```
Better With You <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spoilertv.com%2Fsearch%2Flabel%2FBetter%20With%20You&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=150&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
Brothers and Sisters <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spoilertv.com%2Fsearch%2Flabel%2FBrothers%20And%20Sisters&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=150&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution which is not very good but will work:
Make a Facebook page for each URL.
And then use likeboxes for the pages on your website.

Comment: Thanks, the problem I have is that we've some 200 shows to "like" so create 200+ fan pages is not really an option. Is it possible to maybe use #anchor links?